# How to store form data correctly in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I have a form in React with several controlled inputs.

I always read and had the impression that separately changing states should be stored separately:

For example:

```
const [text1, setText1] = useState();
const [text2, setText2] = useState();
const [text3, setText3] = useState();
```

However, now, because of a specific way of validation, I need to combine all form data in one object, and it should run on every state change (value change).

How should I approach this? Is this [article](https://myselfdev.medium.com/how-to-better-handle-form-data-with-reactjs-145913f6a172) a good guide? Is this best practice and efficient? I'm also afraid of lots of "wasted" data and sloppy performance since `useState` creates immutable objects.

Comment: Overall this sounds like it's mostly opinion-based.  But I'm not aware of any technical reason why all state values *must* be individual values and not complex objects.  Objects are used in state all the time.  One should definitely be aware of things like immutability, reference comparison, etc.  But one should be aware of those things when using the language in general, React is no different.

Comment: So in your opinion, one big state should not be a big deal?

Comment: It's certainly never been a big deal for me.

Comment: Per the article you left, either way is a good way but up to what do you prefer. Try them all and just pick whatever way you like more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that ***all*** states need to be separated into individual hooks (*you could certainly break all your state down this way if you really wanted to*) nor do you want only a single state object with everything in it, but a general rule is that ***related*** values are commonly grouped together into states, while unrelated values are individualized.

Example of related values is your form data. A form is a collection of "inputs" that are often updated together (*user needs to fill in the form*), and validated and submitted ***as a group***.

Examples of unrelated values might be independent toggles, or separate fetched API data. These are all independently referenced, consumed, and updated and should each be their own declared state.

Basically you want to avoid the extremes:

- One single state object with ***everything*** in it. You'd need to copy forward all the unrelated state that isn't being updated for each state update.
- A state for each and every value that may be updated. You'd use several "setStateX" to update values that often update together.

Both cases can affect readability/maintainability, and can make the code less ***DRY***.

How you decide what values are related is where it gets subjective and is really up to you and your projects' needs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/overview), it has a great documentation and quite easy to use. Also, input values automatically come as an object like:

```
    values = {
      text1: 'text1', 
      text2: 'text2', 
      text3: 'text3'
    }
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer, I'll definitely check it out. Unfortunately in this project, I would rather not use any 3rd party libraries.